# create dynamic link based on text input field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, hyperlink, location-href

I'm trying to make a text input field where visitors can enter a value and then hit go or submit.

Based on the digit number they would be send to a new page.

For example if they enter 123 and hit submit it would send them to http://www.example.com/page/123

Could anybody please help me get this up and running? 
Thank you

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: what language are you using? what server?

Comment: If you haven't implement anything I would suggest using bottle in python

Comment: @rm-rf    <input type="text" value="11" id="input">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/page/" id="link">Linked text</a>
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
   link = document.getElementById('link'),
        link.onclick = link.oncontextmenu = link.onmousedown = function () {
            this.href = ('http://www.example.com/page/")+.input.value;
        };
    </script>

Comment: @FarzanMajdani javascript or php

Comment: use javascript to post the number to the server and use python server. That's really simple.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here we go have fun. just copy the code and save it as html. you don't need php or such. it is way too simple to need a server side code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://www.example.com/page/"+inputvalue);

    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>

       <input type="text" value="11" id="input"> 
       <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tnx farzan, but i will use this form in a php script,

Comment: I have wrote the code for you simply just change the url to what you need. and mark this as the accepted answer if that answers your question.

Comment: Great Thanks you. but when click on button not redirect me to url.

Comment: it does, I have tested the code and it works. What is the error on console?

Comment: so please mark my answer as the accepted answer just click on the little tick sign on the left hand side of my answer. Thanks Reza jan

Comment: Note that if you use `window.location.href = "..."` instead of `window.location.replace(...)` the browser back button will work.