# javascript - 'touchstart' event failed to forward text input to links

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I'm tend to make a input field and a button that **works on mobile browser**. When I input `123` on the field and click the button, it should go to `http://example.com/123.html`

Then I combine this two thread [24266205](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266205/create-dynamic-link-based-on-text-input-field) and [22015908](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch/) together. Making the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click touchstart', function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://www.example.com/page/"+inputvalue);
    });
});
```

But when I put it on test, it can be pressed down. But it can't forward me to the page I want.

It does work on Windows, but not on any mobiles. Is there something wrong with the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
<!doctype html>
<input id=input>
<a href="" id=button>link</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://www.example.com/page/"+inputvalue);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: It works, huge thanks. Was stuck in the loop that should be written in the `<head>`, never realise to put it into `<body>`.

Comment: I did, but less than 15 reputation won't display.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location` instead of `window.location.replace` as,

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com/page/"+inputvalue;
```